# Creating array from existing array based on conditions of other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

`itmPaths` is a list with 719255 (integer) values.
`Pt` is a 719255x1 matrix/array with float64 values.
`C` is a 719255x1 matrix/array with float64 values.

I would like to extract the index values where `Pt > C`, and then use those index values to extract the values from `itmPaths` that correspond with those index values, and then store those values in a new array, called `exPaths`. I have tried using the following code:

```
    exPaths = itmPaths[index for index,value in enumerate(Pt-C) if value > 0]
```

In Matlab I can successfully do this using:

```
    exPaths = itmPaths(Pt>C);
```

I would like to keep the code as efficient as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Share the aray's code instead of text to explein them please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension, you could do this, but just as I don't know the exact structure of what you call *matrix* you may adapt, but zipping both allows to keep track of the index (to extract value after) and the values (to apply the condition)

```
exPaths = [itmPaths[idx] for idx, pc in enumerate(zip(Pt, C)) if pc[0] > pc[1]]
```